# 図面を開かずにレイアウトを削除する方法を教えて下さい。

Tags: .net, vb.net, ijcad

IJCAD2016でvb.bet(.net api)を使用して開発を行っています。

モデル以外のレイアウトを全て削除する機能を実装しています。
今回のレイアウト削除にあたり対象図面は開かずにReadDwgFileでDatabaseを読み込み、裏で削除する必要があります。

現在、コーディングがわからずとりあえずLayout をErase（）しています。

```
Using icdTrans As Transaction = db.TransactionManager.StartTransaction
    Try
        Dim ldic As DBDictionary = IcadTrans_GetObject(icdTrans, db.LayoutDictionaryId(), OpenMode.ForWrite)
        For Each dbObj As DBDictionaryEntry In ldic

            'レイアウト取得
            Dim icdLayout As Layout = IcadTrans_GetObject(icdTrans, ldic.GetAt(dbObj.Key), OpenMode.ForWrite)
            Dim btr As BlockTableRecord = IcadTrans_GetObject(icdTrans, icdLayout.BlockTableRecordId, OpenMode.ForWrite)

            'モデル空間は除外
            If UCase(btr.Name) = UCase(BlockTableRecord.ModelSpace) Then Continue For

            'レイアウト削除
            icdLayout.Erase()


            'レイアウト1を新規作成（未実装）


        Next
        icdTrans.Commit()

    Catch ex As System.Exception
        IcadExeptionTrace(ex)
        Return -1
    End Try

End Using
```

この時にIJCAD上でレイアウトタブの切り替えはできなくなっておりますが、タブ自体が残ってしまいます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

図面を開かずにモデル以外のレイアウトを削除（タブも残さない）する方法をご教授願います。

別途質問ですが、LayoutManagerはカレント図面のみを対象としているのでしょうか？
もし、LayoutManagerのDeleteLayoutが使用可能であればそちらで対応したいと考えております。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

レイアウトはブロックテーブルレコードと関連付いている為、レイアウトの操作を行う場合はLayoutManagerクラスを使用してください。
また、ペーパー空間のレイアウトは必ず一つは必要なので、モデル以外のレイアウトを全て削除することはできません。

Comment: HostApplicationServices.WorkingDatabaseでカレントのデータベースを変更し、LayoutManagerクラスで実装できました。また、一度全てのペーパー空間のレイアウトを削除し、新規に1つのレイアウトを作成しました。